# Mysql query : Getting all result in grid view

Tags: mysql

I have four tables :

1. Category
2. Type
3. Disease -  Has associated Disease. Used **childOf** field in the same table for associating the parent-child relationship among parent and child Disease. you can say there are different levels of Disease. Disease level 1 then many other Disease under it. Managing using single table.
4. Treatment for Disease - treatment for Disease

Besides these I have all the other tables for relation between them like

1. category has type
2. type has disease
3. disease has treat

I have a search button . I want to show all the records in the grid view after search. like this . If I do not chosen anything and hit search..

```
Category name  -  Type     - disease                         - Treat
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
record 1       -   type    -  level 1                        - treatment

record 1       -   type    -  level 1.1 (child of level 1)   - treatment

record 1       -   type    -  level 1.2 (child of level )    - treatment
```

Can any body please suggest how can I achieve this. Just a hint. I will write query. I dont know from which table should I need to start get data

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data, I guess your description should rather be

1. Disease has a type
2. Type has a category
3. Disease has a treat
4. Disease can have a parent disease

So you should start with disease, join on type and further on category and also join from disease on treat.

Regarding the hierarchy:

The solution strongly depends on whether your disease-hierarchy has a fixed depth or not. If you have a fixed depth of for example max. 1 child, you could add an outer join from "disease d_child" to "disease d_parent" through the childOF column. You could also alternatively union a query retrieving all "root diseases" with all "child diseases". If your hierarchy has no fixed depth you should consider making multiple queries and combining the results programmatically.

Comment: Ok. You mean I firstly need to fetch all the diseases then then need to get the associated types and categories. right?

Comment: `SELECT d.*
FROM diseases d
JOIN types t ON d.typeId=t.id
JOIN categories c ON t.categoryId=c.id
JOIN treats tr ON d.treatId=tr.id`

Answer (score 0):

Well, that all seems a little complicated and too inter-dependant.

I would have separate tables and a relationship table between them all which links the whole lot of them up and select from that joining the data as and when needed.

This will return rows with all the data on the different disease's that you require.

Question is a little vague though.